# php glob() if empty returns array on windows, none on linux

Tags: php, apache, glob

At the moment I have:

```
$files = array_merge(
        glob($path_ . '*.js'),
        glob($path_ . '*.css'));
```

If the directories are empty on windows it returns an empty array. If they are empty on linux nothing is returned.

This produces this error on linux:
Warning: array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #1 is not an array

- Windows: Apache:2.2.21 PHP:5.3.10
- Linux/Debian: Apache:2.2.16 PHP:5.3.10

After some further research and testing I found that it is a bug in PHP: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53460

Comment: The quick dirty fix would be `@array_merge(...)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php:

> Returns an array containing the matched files/directories, an empty
>   array if no file matched or FALSE on error.

Check if `glob($path_ . '*.js') === FALSE` on linux. In this case, there is probably a permission error or something like this. It should be an empty array if there is no error, as the documentation suggests.

Also check for the case in your files/directory. Windows is case insensitive, that could explain a difference between windows and linux.

Comment: You missed the part which says: On some systems it is impossible to distinguish between empty match and an error.

Comment: Just checked and yes it is returning FALSE. The directory is empty so can't be a file issue.

Comment: What happens if you do a scandir() or a file_exists() on your folder under linux ?

Comment: You have the error `Argument #1 is not an array`, this means that `glob($path_ . '*.css')` does not produce an error ? Does glob() return false only with .js or with both ...*.js and ...*.css. Try that with an empty folder (no js NOR css files). You should obviously have the error in both cases. Also, can you tell us what is in $path variable ?

Comment: After some further research and testing I found that it is a bug in PHP: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53460